# how to update your android app daily without asking the user for update or download

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I'm thinking of uploading my app to the playstore but I haven't tried uploading a single app.

I already know the steps in uploading however there is something that I need to know first.

I want the app to update everyday that doesn't need to notify the user for update. Say for example, in a bible app there is a "Verse of the Day" which is updated daily without downloading an update, just stay connected to the internet and the verse will be updated. I have no idea on how to do that. Is it just uploading a newer apk daily? If so, do I have to notify the user? How do I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Basically, what you are planning to do that can be achieve using API.

If you update database on the server then the API will automatically update the new data in the user phone's when it starts.

You can also implement logic that when any new data is added you can fire a local notification from the app and the user will be notified!

Reference: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-making-remote-api-calls--mobile-17568

**Method 2**

You can create service or background activity that keep on running and calling your API after some interval of time. Whenever new data is received it will fire local notification. (This is not an efficient way because it consumes memory and internet data both)
**E.g.: Alarm Manager**

Reference: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

**Method 3**

You can implement "push notification service", so that you can push notification on the user's device without updating your APK.

Reference: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

P.S. All these method can be done without releasing the new APK on the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your problem is. You have to host your "Verse of the Day" somewhere online and in the app fetch this data from the server. Why do you want to upload a new version of your app for this?

Comment: I don't know how thats why I'm asking. Well, you just gave me an answer. So how do you host the app online and fetch data from a server?

Comment: No, not hosting the app online but only the content you want to get updated every day inside of your app. You can use free services like parse.com or even pastebin.com combined with it's API if you really only need to store text.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest content that you want your app users to have, can use the [Couchbase Mobile](http://bit.ly/MobileCB) feature called [Live Query](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/training/build-first-ios-app/understanding-live-query/index.html) that abstracts out having the user explicitly ask the server for any updates.

When the app is connected to the internet again, content will be updated accordingly if the user's Android app does not have the latest content locally.